# How to add nodes in DevExpress TreeList programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, treelist

I want to add node at specific index in `DevExpress TreeList`. I  have seen [post#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658919/devexpress-treelist-control) and [post#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768986/binding-data-to-the-treelist-control) but unable to get what I need. I only want code that takes the parent node number/id and add child node to it.

I found this function, and i think it will work

```
treelist.AppendNode(object nodeinfo, int parentID);
```

How to give this node info?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, take a look at documentation:
[How to: Create Nodes in Unbound Mode in Code](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5559)

Related link: [Unbound Mode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument177)